# Why does the str.replace python method fail?

Tags: python, string, replace, pyinstaller

I have written a python script to parse a text file. The .py is working fine but when I tried to use pyinstaller to generate the exe file, the program is not working. After some debugging (printing some info during execution from different places into ouput.text) I found that the program stops on the str.replace function.

As this is a built-in method. Should I pass something(module, flags, .. etc) to pyinstaller in order to generate a working exe file?

Pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller -F parse.py
```

parse.py:

```
InputFile = open('./input.txt', 'r')
InputLines = InputFile.readlines()
if len(InputLines ) != 0:
    for line in InputLines: 
        words = line.split()
        if len(words) != 0 : 
            if words[0] == 'ticket':  
               outputText.write('ticket'+words[1]) # to trace the execution 
               ticketObj= ticket(words[1].replace('{', '')) #create new obj 
               outputText.write('replacement done ') # to trace the execution
```

input.text:

```
ticket ticket_1{
ticket details..  
}
```

ouput.text if the generated .exe file runs :

```
ticket ticket_1{
```

ouput.text parse.py file runs :

```
ticket ticket_1{ 
replacement done
```

Comment: I would guess that there is something wrong with either your code or with how you use pyinstaller; but since I cannot see your code I cannot tell you what might be wrong with your code, and since I cannot see how you used pyinstaller I cannot tell you what might be wrong with how you used pyinstaller. Please show the code and show how you used pyinstaller.

Comment: Make sure the exe file you created is in the same folder as the .py file it was created from. So if you have main.py in a src folder, which maybe has a few other .py files and subdirectories, make sure the main.exe file that will be generated by pyinstaller is in the same folder as main.py. Hard to know if this is for sure your problem without more details about your project, but this is the most common problem for the exe not working, since pyinstaller puts the exe in a different folder when it's generated.

Comment: We can't debug this. You've posted a small, unrunnable fragment of your code. Things like `ticket` or `outputText` aren't shown.